# An equivalence of $(X-a)(X-b)>0$ when $a<b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a<b; a,b \in R$, I know that $ (X-a)(X-b)<0 \iff   a<X<b$ what is the equivalent of $ (X-a)(X-b)>0$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a<b.$   Then

$$a<X<b \iff a-X<0<b-X\iff(a-X)(b-X)<0;$$

and

$ X<a<b\; $ or $\; a<b<X \iff  0<a-X<b-X\; $   or  $\; a-X<b-X<0 \iff $

$(a-X)(b-X)>0.  $

---

Note that positive$\times $positive and negative $\times$ negative are positive, while positive$\times$negative is negative.

Comment: More simply, $(X-a)(X-b)<0 \iff a<X<b$ means $(X-a)(X-b)\ge0 \iff $ not $(a<X<b)\iff X\le a $ or $X\ge b$, and $(X-a)(X-b)=0 \iff X=a$ or $X=b$ so $(X-a)(X-b)>0 \iff X<a$ or $X>b$

Answer (score 0):

$AB>0\iff \begin{cases}A>0\\ B>0\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases}A<0\\ B<0\end{cases}$. You can see by yourself by solving this pair of systems with the quantities $A:=X-a$ and $B:=X-b$.

Comment: I can not solve at this stage of my math skills, never solved inequalities pair of systems.